# Data warehouse modelling

Tags: etl, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

Let’s say I have 6 databases, multiple industries, mostly similar schema.

Currently we have dozens of excel files that connect to each DB and query live data (work orders, invoices etc).

As I understand. Creating a separate DW database would be of benefit performance wise, but also when remodelled, would eliminate complex joins currently required by our QA people.

Would it stand to reason, that I would have a denormalized table, called ‘WorkOrder’ which was also a merger of all work orders across 5-6 systems? How would I handle the primary keys of each workorder, when they overlap? I assume a distinct column for each with a unique prefix to designate the origin database?

Should the workorder table contain only common fields, or would all fields make more sense, nulling out those fields where data didn’t exist in the original?

This denormalized table would be easier to query from the QA standpoint, no doubt. But seems to contradict what I’ve read about DW star or snowflake modelling with facts etc?!?

It’s very likely I just don’t get the fundamentals of data warehousing either :)

Comment: What is your final goal? Query these 6 DBs as a single data source (and have an ability to use records from all these 6 DBs in a single report), or eliminate reports duplication (if DB schema is the same, difference is only in the connection string I guess)?

Comment: That's a good question and not one I can answer conclusively at this point. The goal posts will move as time goes on and more and more people start using the spreadsheets, and hopefully (eventually) something more robust, such as powerBI.

For now, to consolidate the databases (to make easier for production to say "What customers did we do work for last month, for these divisions, are there common processes which yield higher ROI". Right now, because each department has a distinct ERP (and thus database), they've implemented separate reports (nearly identical) for each division.

Comment: I can't tell if you need a data warehouse or a consolidated operational database.  A data warehouse is for historical data that does not change,  A consolidated operational database is designed to be updated when local database events happen.  A data warehouse is denormalized.  A consolidated operational database is normalized.

Comment: @Alex.Barylski it might has sense to solve 'spreadsheets hell' first by usage of web-based BI tool where users make view reports / do their ad-hoc queries to existing DBs. Creation of DW with all necessary ELTs may be not so fast as you want (and not cheap for sure). Common reports may just switch between these 6 DBs with a special parameter, for instance (I don't know if PBI can do that, but in my SeekTable this is 100% possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having decided that you need a Data Warehouse, the first decision you need to take is what type of design/database you are going to use. There are quite a few options (Kimball, Inmon, Data Vault, NoSQL, Graph, etc.) but the vast majority of data warehouses follow the basic Kimball Methodology of dimensional modelling e.g. Facts and Dimensions.

If you are going to build a Kimball-style data warehouse (or follow any other methodology) then my first recommendation would be to employ someone with experience who can lead the work. It is very easy to make mistakes when designing a DW but very hard to correct them once people are using it, have built reports against it, etc.

If you're not going to employ someone who knows what they are doing then the next best option is to go on a course and/or read books on the subject. For Kimball, there are really 2 books that should be required reading:

1. [The Data Warehouse Lifecycle Toolkit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0471255475/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i4) : this talks you through all the components involved and the steps to follow in order to deliver a robust data warehouse
2. [The Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00DRZX6XS/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_hsch_vapi_tkin_p1_i0) : this goes through the steps to design a dimensional model

Once you have read and understood these 2 books you will be better placed to understand the terminology and ask specific, focussed questions about any parts of the methodology (or your specific circumstances) that you don't understand.

This is absolutely not meant to be a criticism but from your questions it is very clear that you don't (yet) have the knowledge or experience to be designing and building a data warehouse - and you're not going to be able gain that experience by asking questions on this (or any other) forum.

Comment: 100% I don't understand data analytics, I realize the question was really vague and I apologize for that. Unfortunately, the budget is not there to hire any additional supports. I've built the ERP systems and over time generated basic reports using Excel, embedded charts in the application, experimented with JasperReports, etc. They hired an Excel "wizard" who doubles as QA analyst. I can see the pain points they're encountering, so I've started looking into more scalable, maintainable solutions. Thanks for the input :)